# How fill NA with respect of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill `NaN` values in this way: put the same values as the column `B` if they have the same value in `B`

Example:

```
A    B
nan 'ra'
9   'ra'
5   'pa'
```

So `NaN` value in column `A` should be 9 because they have the same values in column `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].ffill().bfill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A   B
0  9.0  ra
1  9.0  ra
2  5.0  pa
```